# ASP.Net MVC Update entity met with "The entity could not be updated."

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to coding, and am trying to tie up the finishing touches to my personal MVC project. I have done breakpoints to see double-check that the types of the values I'm passing through are matching up, which I believe they are, but it's hard for me to navigate the breakpoints and understand what information I should be looking at.

When I do breakpoints, it skips the final If-statement shown below:

```
if (service.UpdatePromotion(model))
    {
        TempData["SaveResult"] = "The promotion has been updated!";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

If there is any other information needing to be posted, I'll update here if I can or in the comments. I really appreciate anyone who looks this over.

**Controller**

```
// GET: Edit
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var service = CreatePromotionService();
        var detail = service.GetPromotionById(id);
        var model = new PromotionEdit
        {
            PromotionId = detail.PromotionId,
            PromotionName = detail.PromotionName,
            DateFounded = detail.DateFounded,
            Website = detail.Website
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    // POST: Edit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, PromotionEdit model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);

        if (model.PromotionId != id)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "ID Mismatch");
            return View(model);
        }

        var service = CreatePromotionService();

        if (service.UpdatePromotion(model))
        {
            TempData["SaveResult"] = "The promotion has been updated!";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The promotion could not be updated.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Services**

```
public PromotionDetail GetPromotionById(int id)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var entity = ctx.Promotions
                .Single(e => e.PromotionId == id 
                && e.OwnerId == _userId);
            return new PromotionDetail
            {
                PromotionId = entity.PromotionId,
                PromotionName = entity.PromotionName,
                DateFounded = entity.DateFounded.Date,
                Website = entity.Website,
                CreatedUtc = entity.CreatedUtc
            };
        }
    }

    public bool UpdatePromotion(PromotionEdit model)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var entity = ctx.Promotions.Single(e => 
            e.PromotionId == model.PromotionId 
            && e.OwnerId == _userId);

            entity.PromotionName = model.PromotionName;
            entity.IsStarred = model.IsStarred;
            entity.DateFounded = model.DateFounded.Date;
            entity.Website = model.Website;

            return ctx.SaveChanges() == 1;
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class PromotionDetail
{
    [Display(Name = "Promotion ID")]
    public int PromotionId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Promotion Name")]
    public string PromotionName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Founded")]
    public DateTime DateFounded { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Website")]
    public string Website { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedUtc { get; set; }
}

public class PromotionEdit
{
    public int PromotionId { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Promotion Name")]
    public string PromotionName { get; set; }
    public bool IsStarred { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFounded { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Models.PromotionEdit

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Updating Promotion</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PromotionId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PromotionName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PromotionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PromotionName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateFounded, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFounded, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateFounded, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Website, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Website, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Website, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div id="linkColor">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: ctx.SaveChanges() does not always returns 1. It will be good idea to check for positive number rather than 1. SaveChanges() return a number of affected rows. Can you confirm if your database is updated? You should also check if entity is null before updating, using SingleOrDefault, Single will throw exception instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Shout-out to curious.netter in the comments. I was being lazy with the update, not changing anything and clicking Submit. Since there were no changes to apply, the entity would not update, which would skip the last If statement.